# How can I change textview text with list index?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have two activities. Im going to toss a ArrayList that has random integer numbers which is made in activity1 to another activity, named ResultActivity, by intent. Then I want to change the text of textviews of ResultActivity using the index of the list which is tossed. below is a code of ResultActivity I tried.

```
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

    val result = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("result")
    Collections.sort(result)

    val Num1=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Num1)
    Num1.setText(result[0].toString())
}
```

I sorted the list after getting it from activity1.
Then a error occurs in the last  "  Num1.setText(**result[0]**.toString())  " and the content of the error is below.

```
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type ArrayList<Int!>?
```

How should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("result")` returns nullable object. so, u have 2 ways:

1. Make `result` not `nullable` by double bang:

`val result = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("result")!!`

or (more safe way) use Elvis operator:

`val result = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("result") ?: emptyList()`

2. Work with `result` as with nullable list:

`Num1.setText(result?.get(0)?.toString() ?: "")`

Comment: Thank you so much!! problem is solved. Even if I made a list which is not empty, when I use it I have to handle the exception, am I understaning right?

Comment: yes, because `getIntegerArrayListExtra` method doesn't know if passed key is existing in bundle. so by default it's nullable